# Virtuoso Not Including Literal Values in Results when Inferencing is Enabled

Tags: virtuoso, inference

When executing a SPARQL query that takes inference rules into account, Virtuoso is producing unexpected results that do not include plain literal values. If I do not apply inference rules when performing the same query, the plain literal values are returned as expected. What's going on?

Result without Inference Rules:

```
<http://result/subject/1> <http://my/custom/ontology#hasName> "John"
```

Result with Inference Rules:

```
<http://result/subject/1> <http://my/custom/ontology#hasName> <iri_id_123456789_with_no_name_entry>
```

I did some searching around and couldn't find any information discussing what's causing this and how to fix it. By "fix" I mean produce the desired behavior of having plain literal values returned regardless of inference rules being applied.

Comment: At first glance, that looks like a bug. It's hard to tell, without sample data, queries, inference rules, exact Virtuoso version, etc. I strongly suggest you ask such product-specific questions on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [public OpenLink support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or in a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink; we make Virtuoso.)

Comment: @TallTed Well that is an unsatisfying answer. However, I have noticed that the support from Virtuoso tends to be "try this, try that, grab the latest dev build and see if the problem goes away." Not very helpful if you're attempting to educate your audience on what went wrong, why, and how they could have approached the problem differently to avoid the issue altogether. If this sounds like a genuine bug and no one else has any input, then I'll treat it as such and find a workaround. However, I'm not going to document my system to the nth degree so that you can have me grab the latest dev build

Comment: These aren't answers; they're comments on your question, which contains nearly no information. Not knowing your inference rule (which apparently changes the output), nor your query, nor your data -- I can't say whether this result is correct or not, nor explain why either might be so, nor move to fix whatever might be broken, at whatever layer. I don't even know the major version of your Virtuoso (v6, v7, v5, etc.) never mind minor -- which *always* matters when working to diagnose and resolve any software issue!